# Microsoft Graph query parameter

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I use the below query to list all Microsoft 365 groups from our tenant. I would like to add one more filter so that it should only return the groups which have a guest member (Usertype eq 'Guest') in it. Could someone please help

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no such filter to do what you are proposing, you will have to get a list of groups, then use that to query the List members endpoint /groups/{id}/members https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http . then make your own list.
so to summarize, first run your query, get the guids for each group, then grab the members from each group and do some filtering on the client side for usertype.

In theory group/members filtering is possible as of a few weeks ago, with a query like this: [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{id}/members?$count=true&$filter=UserType](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/%7Bid%7D/members?$count=true&$filter=UserType) eq 'Guest'

https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/35630488-enable-filter-on-group-members#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D

note that you need to put in a custom request header of consistencylevel as per the docs.